# Read value of another property in asp.net mvc2 custom attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, properties, custom-attributes, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have made custom attribute in my asp.net mvc2 project:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class IsUsernameValidAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        var username = value.ToString();

        return UserBusiness.IsUsernameValid(username) 
// && value of OtherProperty == true;
    }
}
```

for the model:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [IsUsernameValid]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public bool OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I can get value of UserName, but can I get value of OtherProperty inside custom attribute and use it in return clause and how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `IsValid(Object, ValidationContext)` overload instead?

Comment: Well, I want bool as return value, this overload has ValidationContext return value... Any other help??

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use following code for validation:



     public override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context) 
     {
        var user = context.ObjectInstance as MyClass;
        bool result = ... // Your validation logic here
        return result ? ValidationResult.Success : new     ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(context.DisplayName));
    }

Comment: When I use "public override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)", context is null....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is with a class level attribute. This is often used for validating the `Password` and `PasswordConfirmation` fields during registration.

Grab some code [from there](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/01/09/property-matching-with-data-annotations) as a starting point.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MatchAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
   public override Boolean IsValid(Object value)
   {
        Type objectType = value.GetType();

        PropertyInfo[] properties = objectType.GetProperties();

        ...
   }
}
```